# How can I send data back from ListenableWorker in Android

Tags: android

I am using ListenableWorker in WorkManager, I know I can send data back from a Worker subclass, but I am using a ListenableWorker, and when using the Data.Builder() as is done in Worker class, for this ListenableWorker, I get this error:

Builder.put can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.work)

Additionally, how can I receive the Data in the caller side. I was searching for some example in internet but did not find any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why put() method is showing up in suggestions as there is no information available for it on Documentation itself. You can only use put with type specified like,

```
val data = Data.Builder().putString("key" , "value")
        .build()
```

For all the methods available, check out this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/Data.Builder#summary)